# Custom cell content doesn't show Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3, custom-cell

I want to create a custom table view. I have an UITableViewController:

```
class MainListView: UITableViewController{
var invoceList: [InvoceObject] = []
@IBOutlet var tbMain: UITableView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tbMain.delegate = self
    self.tbMain.dataSource = self
    }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()        
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.invoceList.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell        
    cell.lblBuyerName?.text = self.invoceList[indexPath.row].BUYER_NAME
    cell.lblDate?.text = self.invoceList[indexPath.row].CREATED_AT
    cell.lblPriceGross?.text = self.invoceList[indexPath.row].PRICE + " " + self.invoceList[indexPath.row].CURRENCY

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)      
    return cell
    }
}
```

And my UITableViewCell class:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var lblBuyerName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblDate: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblPriceGross: UILabel!   

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}
```

After build I get an empty cells. I have a number of rows like invoceList.count, but there is no labels and it looks as empty table. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How you are initialising `invoceList` array?

Comment: @NiravD It is no matter, because if I use  `cell.textLabel?.text` (without custom cell) everything is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `UITableViewController` there is an implicit `tableView` property with connected data source and delegate. You should use that to avoid confusion.

And delete the line `self.tableView.register...` if you are using prototype cells.

Answer (score 1):

If the cell's contents are defined in a separate xib file, you need to register that, not the class - if you only register the class, the actual labels are not being created because the class itself does not create them.

```
//Replacing CustomCellNibName with the name of your xib file
tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "CustomCellNibName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

If the cell is being created in the storyboard as a prototype cell, you do not need to register it, but just associate the class with your cell in the storyboard file (under the identity inspector tab, Custom Class), and fill in the name you want to use (in this case, "Cell") under the Attributes inspector field Identifier.

Comment: Cell created in the storyboard as a prototype cell and associated with my CustomCell.swift class. ID is "cell".

Comment: Then it should work if you remove the "self.tableView.register" line

Comment: In my case everything was correct except the way I registered my cell. It was defined in xib file, but I tried to register it via XXXCell.self and as a result wasn't able to see data. Thanks @davedavedave your answer was very helpful.